# how to solve unicodeEncodeError?

Tags: pandas, python-unicode

Does anyone know another option to solve the UnicodeEncodeError in a dataframe ?

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0394' in position 15: character maps to <undefined>
```

I've identified that the row where set the error contain this  symbol

> (ΔT)

this problem arises after importing the excel file and in a column that apparently is empty I get the error, that using python 3.9

I have tried to solve by applying the code below but the error remains the same.

`df['DB_user'].str.encode('ascii', 'ignore').str.decode('ascii')`

Thanks !

Comment: Have you tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9942822/13891969)?

Comment: I have tried but it keeps giving the same error

Comment: Please paste the error text in the question as a code instead of using an image of it, is there a way we can access the excel file you are testing? and the code the makes this error for you.

Comment: If your file contains unicode (which it does), you cannot fit that into ASCII.

Comment: thank you all ! I have solved the error with the following code `df['DB_user']=str(df['DB_user']).encode('ascii', 'ignore')`

Comment: We're happy to hear this, please now answer your question so that future programmers that will come here will be able to see it clearly :)